# Can not install coffeescript using npm on Windows XP

Tags: windows, node.js, coffeescript, npm

I installed Node.js (using windows intaller from http://nodejs.org) with npm. Then I typed

```
npm install -g coffee-script
```

But installation failes. Here is a full log (npm-debug.log): https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5205

The relevant part:

```
30 error Error: connect EAFNOSUPPORT
30 error     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
30 error     at connect (net.js:766:19)
30 error     at net.js:845:9
30 error     at asyncCallback (dns.js:68:16)
30 error     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:121:9)
```

What is the problem and what should I do?

--

Update: I'm running Windows XP (SP3) via Parallels Desktop on MacBook Air.

Comment: Rather than making people go through the log, could you also list specific errors?

Comment: Just go to the first line that says "error", pretty straightforward after that.

Answer (score 0):

That EAFNOSUPPORT would be my first guess. [Try this](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_ip_v6_pro_remove.mspx?mfr=true):

> To remove IPv6
>
> 1. Open Network Connections
> 2. Right-click any local area connection, and then click Properties.
> 3. Click Microsoft TCP/IP version 6 in the list of installed components, and then click Uninstall.
> 4. In the Uninstall Microsoft TCP/IP version 6 dialog box, click Yes.
> 5. Click Close to save changes to your network connection.

Then try installing again.

Comment: I forgot to say: I'm running Windows XP (SP3) via Parallels Desktop on MacBook Air. And IPv6 support is actually even not installed.

Comment: Everything I looked up related to EAFNOSUPPORT tells me it's related to IPV6. Beyond that, sorry, no idea. Google search may help: https://www.google.com/search?q=net.js&oq=net.js&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=94&ie=UTF-8#q=net.js+eafnosupport